# Do you need python to run a python gtk/pyQt application?

Tags: python, asynchronous, gtk, pyqt

I am considering porting what is a small application from a JavaScript bookmarklet for work to a python GTK application. However, while people can run my bookmarklet on either Chrome or Firefox, I don't want to proceed to use Python GTK or PyQT if they need to have python installed. Is there a way to distribute the application with requisite files to avoid needing everyone to install Python on their workstations?

If there are other solutions which offer ability to send async http requests with competent libraries for html dom traversing/parsing (not c#/HAP), I am willing to compromise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also take a look at [PyInstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki). The support for python3 is still experimental, but I have never had any problems so far. I prefer it over py2exe and py2app because of its ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) or [py2app](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app), which can build python applications that contain all needed libraries.